# Meteor accounts-facebook: redirectUrl is not on the same host as the app

Tags: facebook, meteor, https, meteor-accounts

I have built a facebook login with accounts-facebook. Most of the time it works fine, but I have not figured out why it sometimes throws this error when people try to log in:

```
{"line":"431","file":"oauth.js","message":"Error in OAuth Server: 
redirectUrl (http://example.com/login/yes/and/none/hZh6a345235f5Rdb
/m2Mzs9nTo654645FBhP) is not on the same host as the app
(https://example.com/)","time":{"$date":1521904059120},"level":"warn"}
```

I have not been able to reproduce this.

I have added

```
"https://example.com/",
"https://example.com/_oauth/facebook",
"https://example.com/login/:var1/and/:var2/:var3/:var4"
```

and here are my other settings:
[image: my facebook settings]

Comment: Well your redirect URI value is an HTTP URL, whereas everything you have specified is HTTPS ... FYI, once strict mode becomes mandatory (soon), you won't be able to pass such variables everywhere in your URL any more - the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs you specify in the app settings will have to match the actual values used exactly (with the `state` query string parameter being the singular exception.)

Comment: hm ok that is sad. So it would have to be `https://example.com/login?var1=val&var2=val&var3=val` ? How do you handle this in Meteor? like getting the parameters from there? Thanks for your help :)